# ERRO ao fazer o UPLOAD Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mysqli

Senhores,

Estou tendo o seguinte erro "The "/tmp/php63F4kk" file does not exist or is not readable." no Laravel, estou fazendo a inserção das informações da seguinte maneira:

```
if($request->hasfile('foto'))
     {

            $image = $request->file('foto');
            $name = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName = time() . '.' . $name; 
            $image->move(public_path().'/fotos/sobre/', $fileName);  
            $data = $fileName;  

     }

    $sobre = new SobreDestino();

    $sobre->destino_id = $request->id_destino;
    $sobre->descricao = $request->sobre;
    $sobre->titulo = $request->titulo_foto;
    $sobre->foto = $data;
    $sobre->save();
```

Onde posso estar errando?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o primeiro trecho:

```
$extension = $request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalExtension();     
$name = uniqid();
//salva um nome baseado no id
$nameFile = $name.'.'.$extension; 
$path = $request->file('imagem')->storeAs('fotos/sobre/',$nameFile,local));
```

E esse trecho:

```
$sobre->foto = 'storage/fotos/sobre/'.$nameFile;
```

Depois execute no comand:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Com isso você fara os uploads no storage da aplicação e terá um link simbólico na public da aplicação. Assim é a forma descrita na documentação! Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado deu certo!